# Simple calculation on for loop

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a beginner in Java. I am confused, why n here is equal to 5.
To my understanding, this should be 0 because n will undergo five times (n*i) with i increasing by 1 each step(i.e: n = 1 * 0, n = 0 * 2, n = 0 * 3 and so on).

```
    int n = 1; 
    int i = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++); 
        n *= i;
        System.out.print(n);
```

Comment: for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++);

with the semicolon in the for loop will iterate in the same line, ie) iterate the i value.
After 4 iterations i value will be 4, which is equal to 4 and iterate one more time which will give the value as 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++); 
                       ^
```

is a loop with an empty body that only increments i to 5, so `n *= i` will perform `n = 1 * 5`.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    n *= i;
}
```

will do what you expected.

Comment: can I suggest actually opening and closing the brackets for a *better* clarity?

Comment: @Eugene Sure, that can certainly help.